# An adjective to describe a very interesting and full-of-fun lesson

Tags: word-request

Here is the situation: 
One subject teacher is wrapping up his successful lesson - all kids in the class were listening to him with a lot interest and participated in all activities during the lesson. The homeroom teacher who was present in the classroom during the whole lesson comes up to him and says:

"Very ...!"

Here the homeroom teacher wants to say that the lesson was very interesting and was fun for children. I need only one word, adjective, right after "Very". What would be the best adjective here?

1. lovely
2. lively
3. entertaining
4. amusing
5. fun
6. funny
7. engaging
8. interesting
9. riveting
10. playful

    or what?

Comment: All your adjectives have at least *slightly* different meanings / connotations. How are we supposed to know exactly what the teacher's thinking (and therefore which word best matches his intent)?

Comment: "How are we supposed to know exactly what the teacher's thinking (and therefore which word best matches his intent)?" - By reading my question more carefully: "...Here the homeroom teacher wants to say that the lesson was very interesting and was fun for children..."

Comment: You yourself have suggested *interesting* and *fun* as possible choices, but you've characterized the lesson itself as both of those plus *successful*. Which word is more important? All of them? Does your particular choice of possible alternatives imply that the lesson was also *riveting*? Or are you actually asking for whichever single English word comes closest in meaning to *all* your alternatives ***at the same time**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Or are you actually asking for whichever single English word comes closest in meaning to all your alternatives at the same time?" - Yes! Please, don't pay attention to how I have characterized the lesson. Just look at what thought the home room teacher wants to express. She only wants to say that the lesson was interesting and fun. So I only want to see if there is any adjective in English that would convey both of these meanings and be best fit in the presented grammatical structure (that is, in the two-word sentence that starts with "Very" and ends in that adjective).

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Surely a *teacher* (even if he's only dealing with infants) would be primarily interested in the lesson being ***productive*** (that the children actually *learn* something). Even if there was a specific English word that somehow straddled ***interesting*** and ***fun*** equally (or in whatever proportion the teacher intends), it probably wouldn't be appropriate unless it also included allusions to ***educational, instructive*** or similar.

Comment: [***Omoshiroi** has basically two meanings. One is **'interesting'**, another one is **'funny'***.](http://www.lang-8.com/135694/journals/653782) But that's Japanese. I don't know if there's an equivalent single-word English term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Surely a teacher (even if he's only dealing with infants) would be primarily interested in the lesson being productive" - It's a situation in Asia, where  no productivity or instructiveness is demanded from a white-face teacher, but rather his/her ability not to frighten children by his/her unusual non-Asian look and the ability not to be boring throughout the whole lesson. It is especially that way during the demo lesson (the lesson that an English teacher gives for the first time).

Comment: [*The BBC informs, educates and entertains – but in what order?*](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2014/jul/01/bbc-inform-educate-entertain-order) If there was a single word for all those ambitions, I'm sure the BBC would have written it into their charter.

Comment: Anyway, from your last comment, it seems that "productive" for this particular hapless "teacher" simply means *successfully break down racial distrust using humour*, which is just too weird a context for me to fully engage with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'If there was a single word for all those ambitions, I'm sure the BBC would have written it into their charter" - Interesting, thank you. Of course, breaking down the distrust and establishing a rapport is only a demand for the first few lessons, after which the educational part is also expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those words, nor any other single word that I can think of fully and exactly conveys the meaning "that the lesson was very interesting and was fun for children". If the observer wants to fully convey this meaning, a longer statement would be needed.

"entertaining", "amusing", or "fun" don't really convey the "interesting" aspect, and "interesting" doesn't really convey the "fun for the children" aspect. Perhaps "engaging" is the closest of the suggested words.

A longer speech such as:

> Very well done! That was both interesting and fun.

conveys the intended meaning fully, but of course the question says that a longer speech is not wanted.

Comment: again an answer is dowenvoted with no reason, no comment at all. I think this practice should be prohibited.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I consider this answer fully addressing my request. I gave it +1 and marked it as the best answer.